# Entity Framework Core automatically inserts double quotes in Oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app, and I want to use the integrated Identity platform to handle user roles and authentication.

Since this web app must be cross-database, I need to make this work on a Oracle autonomous database. So I've installed the `Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore` package from NuGet, and switched to the `UseOracle` method in the `ConfigureServices` method of my `Startup.cs` file.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
        {
            // options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("OracleConnection"))
        });
```

The connection can be established, but here's the issue: when prepping up the `UserManager` and creating User Roles in `Startup.cs`, any standard method that EF Core invokes actually executes a query with double quotes around object names, e.g. doing this

```
private async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
   //Custom roles 
   var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

   string[] roleNames = { "Admin" };

   IdentityResult roleResult;

   foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
   {
       var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);

       if (!roleExist)
       {
           // create the roles and seed them to the database: Question 1
           roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
       }
   }

   await CreateUser(serviceProvider, "Admin");
}
```

This code executes this query:

```
SELECT "a"."Id", "a"."ConcurrencyStamp", "a"."Name", "a"."NormalizedName"
FROM "AspNetRoles" "a"
WHERE "a"."NormalizedName" = :normalizedName_0
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

which fails.

It searches for an `"AspNetRoles"` table, double quotes means it searches EXACTLY that, and thus it doesn't exist because tables are all uppercase in Oracle autonomous database, and cannot be CamelCase. I get an error ORA-00942.

I can't figure out how to make EF Core **NOT** use double quotes without reverting to the DevArt Oracle package.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can make EF to pass correct names (uppercase ones) rather than removing double quotes. You can achieve this either by manually specifying needed table names or implementing a naming convention.

Comment: @GuruStron How can I achieve this with `AspNet Identity` tables? I cannot specify the `modelBuilder` for `AspNetRoles` in the `DBContext` class. Plus, it has to be case insensitive, since we're building a cross-database application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I understood the problem wasn't only for `Identity Provider` tables.

So I've implemented `linq2db` and `linqToDb.Identity` and made it work by putting

```
OracleTools.DontEscapeLowercaseIdentifiers = false;
```

in the `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup.cs`.

Quick note: `LinqToDb.Identity` `NuGet` package is stuck on a May 2021 release which is incompatible with recent `Linq2DB` packages due to various missing references to `this` (e.g. `this.GetTable`) in the `IdentityDataConnection` class, so you might as well download the source code and include it in your project (or make a class library out of it) and fix the class.

Repo link: https://github.com/linq2db/LinqToDB.Identity